# What should I do if I didn't recieve the verification email for Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I entered my email right, but I still didn't get the code.

Comment: Support contact  related only to Ubuntu one [Here](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to contact the ISD team - https://forms.canonical.com/sso-support/

Comment: As far as https://forms.canonical.com/sso-support/ is concerned I got the message:
Sorry, the page you are looking for was not found

Answer (score 2):

Check the spam folder on your e-mail. I think mine went there.